# TemplateSyntaxError at / Could not parse the remainder: 'product.tk' from ''main-product-detail'product.tk'

Tags: python, html, django

I'm stuck on a problem that I solve most of the time but now, when I place the links in my home.html files for the product detail page, an error appears: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Impossible to analyze the rest: 'product.tk' of ''main-product-detail'product.tk' I checked everywhere and modified things but nothing changed.

take a look at my code and tell me where is the error

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
from django.db.models import Q
from main.models import Cart
from command.models import *
from notification.models import *
from user.models import *
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.viewsets import ReadOnlyModelViewSet
from main.serializers import ProductSerializer                # CategorySerializer
from .utils import get_cart_data


import validators

from amazon import scrape, scrape_search


def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    product_recommadeds=Product.objects.all().order_by('-date')
   # new_products= Product.objects.filter(date='')
    cart_id = request.COOKIES.get('cart_id')
    cart = None
    cart_count = 0
    if cart_id:
        try:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
            cart = get_cart_data(cart)
            cart_count = cart and len(cart['cart_products']) or 0
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'panier non trouvé: {e}')
    response = render(request, 'main/home.html', locals())
    if not cart and cart_id:
        response.delete_cookie('cart_id')
    return response


def product_detail(request,tk):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=tk)
    similar_products = Product.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector(
        'name', 'description', 'keywords', 'price','color')).filter(Q(search=product.keywords) | Q(search__icontains=product.keywords.split(' ')))[:12]

    product = vars(product)
    if product['is_external'] and product['url']:
        print(product['external_id'])
        data = scrape(
            external_id=product['external_id'], headers=request.META)
        print('look data: ', data)
        if data:
            print(data)
            product = {**product, **vars(data)}

    is_in_cart = False
    quantity = 1
    try:
        cart_id = request.COOKIES.get('cart_id')
        cart_product = CartProduct.objects.get(
            cart_id=cart_id, product_id=product['id'])
        is_in_cart = True
        quantity = cart_product.quantity
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'erreur dans product_detail: {e}')
    print(locals())
    return render(request, 'main/product_detail.html', locals())
```

home html:

```
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="axil-best-seller-product-area bg-color-white pb_sm--30 cardbottom">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="section-title-wrapper"> <span class="title-highlighter highlighter-secondary"><i
              class="far fa-shopping-basket"></i>Nos Nouveaux Produits</span>
          <h2 class="title">Decouvrez Nos Nouveautés</h2>
        </div>
        {% for product in products %}
        <div
          class="new-arrivals-product-activation-2 slick-layout-wrapper--15 axil-slick-arrow arrow-top-slide product-slide-mobile">

          <div class="slick-single-layout">
            <div class="axil-product product-style-three">
              <div class="thumbnail"> <a href="{% url 'product-detail'product.tk %}"> <img class="product-image"
                    data-sal="zoom-out" data-sal-delay="100" data-sal-duration="1500" src="{{product.image_url}}"
                    alt="Produit Images">
                </a>
                <div class="product-hover-action">
                  <ul class="cart-action">
                    <li class="wishlist"><a href="#" class="btn-favorite" data-id="{{product.id}}"><i
                          class="far fa-heart"></i></a></li>
                    <li data-id="{{product.id}}" class="select-option btn-add-to-cart"><a
                        href="{% url 'cart' %}">Ajouter</a></li>
                    <li class="quickview"><a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#quick-view-modal"><i
                          class="far fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-content">
                <div class="inner">
                  <h5 class="title"><a
                      href="{% url 'product-detail'product.tk %}">{{product.name|truncatechars:60}}</a></h5>
                  <div class="product-price-variant"> <span class="price current-price">${{product.price}}</span> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {%endfor%}
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('apropos/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('panier/', views.cart, name='cart'),
    path('products/<int:tk>/detail/', views.product_detail, name='main-product-detail'),#product detail urls
    path('products/<int:id>/add_to_cart/',
         views.add_product_to_cart, name='add_product_to_cart'),
    path('external_products/<int:id>/', views.external_product_detail,
         name='external_product_detail'),
    path('external_products/<int:id>/add_to_cart/',
         views.add_external_product_to_cart, name='add_external_product_to_cart'),
    path('products/', views.home, name='products'),   #product list urls
    path('shop/', views.shop, name='shop'),       
    path('search/', views.search, name='search')
```

the problem is here

```
<a href="{% url 'product-detail'product.tk %}">
```

I have modified several times but nothing is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django templates the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) is a function that expects one or more arguments separated with space. In your case the first argument is a string: the name of the endpoint, the second is a primary key stored in the `product.id` variable. You just need to put one space between them and it will work:

```
<a href="{% url 'main-product-detail' product.id %}">
```

Note: check the product detail's endpoint name in the templates. In the the `urls.py` you named it `main-product-detail` but sometimes you used just `product-detail`.

Comment: I put the space and arrange on the url side and another error occurred                                              NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'product-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']    , here : '{% url 'product-detail'  product.tk %}">

Comment: Replace `product-detail` with `main-product-detail` and the `product.tk` with `product.id`. Or you can also rename the products detail endpoint in `urls.py` to `product-detail`.

Comment: it's done but still this error                                                                     
 NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'product-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Comment: No, you didn't, that's what the error message is about, you did not replace all `product-detail` with `main-product-detail`.

Comment: There: 'products/<int:id>/', views.product_detail, name='product-detail') and I still have the same error

Comment: Ok, so now it's the second argument. Did you replace all `product.tk` with `product.id` at the URL-generating? If so, could you check what is the value of `product.id` when the error occurs?

Comment: where to check this value?, I did not understand

Comment: E.g. `{{ product.id }}`. But first replace `product.tk` with `product.id` in the template, it should work.

Comment: it does not work either, everywhere so I had put product.tk, I replaced it with product.id but nothing works. I am exceeded

Comment: Let's go back one step. Delete everything from the for-loop and just print out the `product.id`: `{% for product in products %}{{ product.id }}{% endfor %}`. What do you see?

Comment: Thanks a lot
 the problem was in the scr for the images
                              
    <a href="{% url 'product-detail' product.id %}"> <img class="product-image"
                    data-sal="zoom-out" data-sal-delay="100" data-sal-duration="1500" src="{{product.image_url}}"
                    alt="Product Images">